# How do I add all EntityTypeConfiguration<> from current assembly automatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

How do I add all EntityTypeConfiguration<> from current assembly automatically?

```
public class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("Entities")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    // ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        foreach(var configuration in this.GetAllConfigurations())
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configuration);
        }
    }

    private ... GetAllConfigurations()
    {
        // TODO: Get all configurations from current ASSEMBLY
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It should be very easy as `DbModelBuilder` offers special method for that. Try add this within `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);
```

Answer (score 12):

Simpler Answer

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
```