# Cannot create an instance of because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6

[image]

I am creating an instance dynamically using reflection.

```
var typesTR = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BGenericConfigurationClass<>)).GetTypes()
            .Where(type =>
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace) &&
                    (type.Namespace == "EntitiesConfiguration"))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null
                           && type.BaseType.IsGenericType
                           &&
                           (type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BGenericConfigurationClass<>) ||
                            type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(CGenericConfigurationClass<>) ));

foreach (var type in typesTR)
{
                
    dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
}
```

and my exception is following :-

```
"Cannot create an instance of CGenericConfigurationClass`1[T] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true."
```

Comment: The image isn't helpful at all. Please remove it and show code instead. Also, note that EF has a built-in function to discover `EntityTypeConfiguration` classes in an assembly.

Comment: i want to use multi-level inheritance using EntityTypeConfiguration class of ef. Give me any idea or any solution.

Comment: *Give me...* Linguistically that's imperative, or "commanding". Doesn't work well at Stack Overflow where everybody volunteers in helping others. One of these volunteers correctly explained to you that you need `type.MakeGenericType` -- to which you didn't give any substantial response. Again, I suspect you're trying to reinvent the wheel that EF [already provides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222663/861716) but you don't respond to that either.

Comment: sorry if you feel of my wrong word selection but i told exact point English is your mother language but i converted every sentence before writing..  i am not commanding i deeply appreciate  you replying and share my problem solution, thanks sir or brother take any word that you like. i feel guilty and shame rising of behavior mistake... please share skype or email address i share whole project.

Comment: No hard feelings, just explaining how SO works. But I'm also asking to respond to suggestions given so far.

Comment: @GertArnold I disagree with that, I'd say the image shows what the OP's mind is doing, which is what we're working with as answerers.  Keep the image!  It represents the OP's perception of the problem.

Comment: @ranalaiqueahmed were you able to find a fix for the solution

Answer (score 8):

It looks like one of the types in `typesTR` is a generic type and you are attempting to create an instance of that type without specifying the generic type parameters. As an example, this is as if you were attempting to create an instance of `List<>`  but without providing the type between the angle brackets <>. This is not possible, `Activator.CreateInstance()` must be given a "closed generic type".

To do this, you could do something like the following, but based on your example, I don't think this will be very useful since you need to create numerous configuration instances and you may not know what generic type to pass in.

```
var t = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(SomeClassToBeUsedAsGenericTypeParameter));
dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
...
```

My guess is that `typesTR` has more types in it than you were expecting and includes one of the base classes which is generic. I think it should only include DClass and EClass, but is including one of the base classes.

Comment: sir i want to use multi-level inheritance using EntityTypeConfiguration class of entity framework. the above picture show main scenario  Give me any idea or any solution

Answer (score 1):

In my case, which of course is different, but also has some similarities with the problem raised in the question, I managed to make part of my Entity mappings in EF generic by using the following code

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
 {
     RegisterMaps(builder);
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 }

 private static void RegisterMaps(ModelBuilder builder)
 {
     var mapLists = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.Namespace)
                && typeof(IEntityMap).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
                && type.IsGenericType == false 
                && type.IsClass).ToList();

     foreach (var item in mapLists)
     {
         Activator.CreateInstance(item, BindingFlags.Public | 
         BindingFlags.Instance, null, new object[] { builder }, null);
     }
}
```